# What is the purpose of "Perceived Types" in Windows 7-10?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, file-management, file-types

Besides determining the default folder type in Windows Explorer, what is the purpose of "Perceived Types" for files in Windows 7-10?

Are there any advantages or disadvantages to setting the perceived type for custom file extensions?

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to group files of like types into broad categories. For example images such as jpg, png and ico.

The advantage is that you can then do operations on like type files.

For example, if your new file type is image related and you want to rename it while renaming all image files than give it the perceived type 'Image.'

Comment: I'm not understanding your example.  Can you expound on it in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

**[PerceivedType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-perceivedtypes)** corresponds to the **Kind** column in **Explorer**. It's a way "rolling up" file types that similar in nature. Especially useful for searching to avoid a list of file extensions.
Add the **Kind** colum to a **Details** view in **Explorer** and explore :)
Take a look at:

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap
```

as well.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  And thanks for the registry reference.  If you don't use Explorer, and your file manager doesn't do anything with the Perceived Type, do Perceived Types effect/impact anything at all in the system (for Windows 7-10)?

Comment: Hard to say (at least for me - LOL). Is Explorer still your shell? It provides the common dialogs used by many programs. It also may affect waht appears in the context menu for items.

Comment: Good questions. Yes, Explorer is still the shell. It does provide common dialogs used by many programs.  Context menus are an interesting point as well, although I'm currently unclear if Perceived Types impact them.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I imagine that PerceivedType is what ties file extensions to the audio/image/text/video entries under `HKCR\SystemFIleAssociations` . All of those appear to add verbs to the context menu.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the PerceivedType in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\${Extention}  (powershell:> Set-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\${Extention} -Name 'PerceivedType' -Value "text")`
Then in the explorer, the preview window will show the contents of files with that extention as a txt-like contents.

If you do so for all script and source extentions you know, you have a preview of all scripts and sources.

For example the next powershell makes all the given extentions 'text' (which can ruin your life as it just overwrites current settings):

```
Get-Item Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\* -Include ".ahk",".cfg",".hs",".inf",".json",".log",".md",".menu",".note",".pcs",".ps1",".psd1",".psm1",".py",".reg",".txt",".ucf",".vbs",".xml" | Set-ItemProperty -Name PerceivedType -Value text
```